# Изменение расположения полей и текста на JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Имеется следующий код:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    private static JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");
    private static JTextField port = new JTextField(20);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = getFrame();
    }

    static JFrame getFrame(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setBounds(750,250,500,500);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        portText.setLocation(10,10);
        jPanel.add(portText);
        port.setLocation(10,30);
        jPanel.add(port);
        jPanel.revalidate();
        return jFrame;
    }
}
```

Однако при выполнении текст и текстфилд находятся по центру, хотя я вроде как задаю по координатам, чтобы они находились друг под другом. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;


class Main {

  private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");
  private static JTextField port = new JTextField(20);


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    JPanel panel = (JPanel) jFrame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);


    // x = frame.width/2-width/2
    portText.setBounds(500 / 2 - 50, 20, 100, 10);
    panel.add(portText);


    //             x             y   width height
    port.setBounds(500 / 2 - 50, 50, 100, 30);
    panel.add(port);


    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setBounds(750, 250, 500, 500);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

надо создавать jPanel основанную на JFrame, а не через new JPanel;

Comment: код правильный, пояснение - нет. Автору вопроса мешает layout manager, который вы убираете `panel.setLayout(null);`. Кроме того, компонентам нужно было бы задать размер через `setSize` или как у вас сразу размер и положение через `setBounds`

Comment: @zRrr Вы абсолютно правы, огромное вам спасибо!